# Background push working for iOS7 but not for iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've got an app which is using background push, things are working fine when the app runs on a device with iOS 7 but the pushes are not being delivered to the app if its in the background if its running on a device with iOS 8.

I have this as the registration code:

```
- (void) registerForRemoteNotification
{
    // Check for the presense of iOS8 notification API
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)])
    {
        NSLog(@"iOS8 detected");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS version < 8
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
}
```

I have also tried this variant:

```
- (void) registerForRemoteNotification
{
    // Check for the presense of iOS8 notification API
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)])
    {
        NSLog(@"iOS8 detected");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
        UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS version < 8
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
}
```

This is the content of the push payload:

```
aps =     {
    "content-available" = 1;
    somePayload = "The payload";
    sound = "";
};
```

This is what is happening:

```
1) On iOS7 when app is in the foreground -> push is delivered to the app as expected
2) On iOS7 when app is in the background -> push is delivered to the app as expected
3) On iOS8 when app is in the foreground -> push is delivered to the app as expected
4) On iOS8 when app is in the background -> push is NOT delivered to the app
5) On iOS8 when app is in the foreground and running via Xcode -> push is delivered to the app as expected
6) On iOS8 when app is in the background and running via Xcode -> push is delivered to the app as expected
```

(In every case didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: gets invoked and didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: doesn't.)

I don't know if its relevant but look at the difference between 4) and 6), I'm seeing a difference between if the app is running via Xcode or not.

My question is why is the push not being delivered to the app for case 4)?
 It works for iOS7, and AFAICT the code for registering for remote notifications when running on iOS8 is correct (and indeed, it does work if executing the app via Xcode hence it must be correct), hence why is it not working when the app is running independent of Xcode on iOS8?

** UPDATE. After posting the bounty for this I went browsing the Apple developer forums. Seems lots of people are having similar issues. For some wifi has to be enabled to get the background pushes, for me however that doesn't work - I have to be charging the phone to get them. If its not charging (even if the battery is full) then they don't get delivered. Apple say what they've done regarding background push for iOS 8 is deliberate and not a bug, but my conclusion is they've either screwed up or done something so illogical as to be considered a screw up. So I'm hoping they'll realize its a ****ing mess what they've done and change it in a future release.

If you want to get the background head over to the relevant dev forum and read some relevant threads.

Comment: I've got a very similar issue. Does your app show up in Settings --> Notification?

Comment: Yes it does, how about your app?

Comment: Mine doesn't. Also, it receives notifications while in foreground but doesn't in the background.

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with the content of your push message? Originally when background push was first released, I found that the only way I could get it to be delivered in the background was to add a 'sound' section to the push. Recently I came across this post http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/troubleshooting/ios-background-push.html. So it seems Apple have an absolutely ludicrously ridiculous and just stupid requirement for the content of the push for what is meant to be silent push. It no longer makes it work for me, but maybe it will for you, the sound name can be empty.

Comment: You're code is a little off for iOS8, it should be the second variant, plus implementing the following method: - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}     ..... I'm not convinced it will solve the problem but worth a shot

Comment: I've got that implemented, I just didn't post it in the question, I've tweaked the question to make that explicit.

Comment: Do you sure, that you enabled notifications for your app in your iOS 8 device settings?

Comment: I  dont have a solution but I can at least tell you arent crazy imaging things :D I got the same issue! SOMETIMES ios8 will deliver the push but mostly not -- connect it to xcode and it works 100% -- all depends on the device used

Comment: Which method from app delegate you're using to get notifications? (i mean didReceive...)

Comment: @Daij-Djan. The reason it works when you are connected to Xcode is because its drawing power from the usb cable. I have discovered with iOS8 some devices only ever receive push notification in the background if they are being charged when the push arrives. Try it with you power cable, plug it in and it will work, unplug it and it won't!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set Push notification entitlement keys.

aps-environment
    ,Receive push notifications in iOS

Please refer this link [Push Notification Entitlement Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingLocalAndPushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH3-SW2)

Comment: If that was the problem then the app wouldn't receive ANY pushes. My problem is not that the app doesn't receive pushes in general, but that it doesn't receive background pushes.

Comment: Just a check, that background notification is ON in the settings.

Comment: The background modes have "Background fetch" and "Remote notifications" enabled, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is needed to receive remote notifications on background in iOS8. Apple has changed the methods needed to be called for that. First, they have deprecated the method `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` and now you are supposed to use `registerForRemoteNotifications`. But that's not everything that change — you still have to specify types of allowed notifications. 
Here's from documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerForRemoteNotifications):

> If you want your app’s push notifications to display alerts, play sounds, or perform other user-facing actions, you must call the registerUserNotificationSettings: method to request the types of notifications you want to use. If you do not call that method, the system delivers all push notifications to your app silently. Because the registration process takes into account the user’s preferred notification settings, requesting access to user-facing notification types also does not guarantee that they will be granted. To find out what notification settings are available, use the currentUserNotificationSettings method.

Try calling `currentUserNotificationSettings` now and you'll see that no types of notifications are allowed, so no wonder they aren't received.

Try this:

```
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
```

It does the thing!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me, my code already has the code you have posted. The apple documentation says this: " If you do not call that method, the system delivers all push notifications to your app silently." But you seem to have got it working by doing the opposite of what the documentation says!

Answer (score 0):

The following has been working in my apps for iOS7 and iOS8:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's what I have already. I've discovered Apple have deliberately done something to background push in iOS8 and are not delivering in the pushes in some circumstances but they haven't published details. I've got 5 phones and it works all the time with 3 of them, intermittently with one, and hardly ever with another. So its not a coding issue, its other factors which Apple won't disclose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I found I had a issue with Apples documentation, I use Parse and it has a better section for help

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"asdasd" clientKey:@"asdasd"];
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                             categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"asdasd" clientKey:@"asdasd"];
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's no difference between this and the code I posted in the question, where it says "I have also tried this variant:", other than the UIApplication methods are called in a different order. Are you implying the order is vitally important?

Comment: You should try, I do remember I was having issues until I used this code, just try it.
I will also look back in my code and see what else I did to fix the issue.